# Differentiating between two datasets

Tags: python

I have two measurements of data, for simplicity they approximate to one sinus wave and one cosinus wave, so for the question I wll act as if they are.

The correct values for these waves are contained in two arrays, a and b. However, some of the values are swapped; that is, some of the values that belong to wave a are actually stored in b, and the other way around. I'm looking for a reliable way to discern when the values are swapped. How would I best approach this?

Currently I've tried to see if the difference between two consecutive results is larger than the difference it has with the other table, however this has the drawback that it 'reverses' the waves each time this is true. Is there a better way?

```
sins, coss = [], []

random_deviants = [11, 12, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]

for i in range(50):
    if i not in random_deviants:
        sins.append(math.sin(i/4))
        coss.append(math.cos(i/4))
    else:
        sins.append(math.cos(i/4))
        coss.append(math.sin(i/4))
    
    
plt.plot(sins)
plt.plot(coss)
plt.show()
```

The signals are switched. What is the best way to recognize these switched points and restore the natural sinus and cosinus waves?

[image: plot]

Comment: If your data are exactly sine and cosine something can be worked out using the analytical equations, but since your real data just approximate to sine and cosine, this might not work out well. Do you know at least how good is the approximation? Do you know, for example, by how much at maximum the real data deviate from the sine or cosine function?

Comment: Assuming the signals are close to sin and cosine wave, there delta(current sample value -previous sample value) will change sign (+ to - or vice versa) only at their peak or crest. But that will never happen simultaneously. If they are happening simultaneously then we can assume that signal values have been swapped.

Comment: You could assume that if delta y between a point p and next point p+1 is greater than a given threshold, points are swapped. So point p+1 should alway be close to point p, at least the closest one.

Comment: @Valentino I do not know that sadly